# Which tables are affected in Magento 1.9 when I empty the cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, sales-quote

I am working with a Magento 1.9. I had added some products (Simple products) to my cart as a logged in user and saved it for checkout it later. But I haven't placed it as an order. I empty that cart.

Which are the tables affected by this process while I am emptying the cart? There is no changes in `sales_flat_quote` and `sales_flat_quote_items`, after doing this .But it is removed from my cart. How does Magento know that my cart is empty? Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add product to the cart, magento will have entries in `sales_flat_quote`,`sales_flat_quote_item` and `sales_flat_quote_address`

ie: Carts are saved to the `sales_flat_quote` table

The items in the basket are saved to `sales_flat_quote_item`, linked by the quote's `entity_id`

Most of the entries in  `sales_flat_quote_address` will be null when you create the cart. later it will be updated on checkout with proper addresses.

So when you remove a product from the cart, that product will be removed from the `sales_flat_quote_item` and

`item_qty,item_count` and `prices` will be removed from the `sales_flat_quote`

This is the usual working flow. If you are not working on production  please do truncate your quote tables and add product to the cart to see this changes. I think you might have missed the changes. Please do check the updated date of entries and you will definitely see the difference.